# Process location data in the background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am currently receiving location updates and want to periodically send an update to a server via an api call. Everything works when launching the app but updates in the background are really inconsistent.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
var lastUpdateTime: Double?

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation)
{
    userLocation = newLocation

    if let lastUpdate = lastUpdateTime {
        let thisUpdate = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        let timeInterval = thisUpdate - lastUpdate

        if timeInterval > 60 {
            if
                let latitude = userLocation?.coordinate.latitude,
                let longitude = userLocation?.coordinate.longitude
            {
                // Make API call to update location
                lastUpdateTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            }
        }

    } else {
        lastUpdateTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    }

}
```

I've read what I can find regarding background tasks and location updates but honestly I'm a bit lost. If it helps, the api call is made through Alamofire if that has an effect on how often it gets executed.

EDIT:

Added CLLocationManager options...

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: Did you properly activate background location? 
What are your settings on the location ? (the refresh period for example)

Comment: Hi @thibautnoah, I'll update the OP with the CLLocationManager options

Comment: That seems good, could you define more precisely what you call inconsistent?
I assume you api call is correct, if so the problem lies within the background updates, have you checked this tutorial? :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Comment: Yeah I followed that guide to set up the background updates. I've put a print in the 'didUpdateToLocation' delegate method to check when that was called and it is occasionally executed while the app is running (although that isn't particularly consistent) but once I enter the background it doesn't appear to be called at all

Answer (score 0):

For getting location updates in background , app should enable 'location update' background mode in capabilities tab in project settings.
Apart from this, required background location key(*NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription*) needs to be added into the info.plist file. If these two things are done correctly, app will receive location updates continuously in background when call 'startUpdatingLocation'